# Move matched string to end in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, string-matching

I am doing a `GROUP_CONCAT` to display names in the format of

```
Lastname1, Firstname1; Lastname2, Firstname2
```

There are occasions where the `lastname` also contains strings enclosed in curved brackets - `(` and `)`. Since these will get displayed in the middle of the concatenated string I'm trying to move it to the end.

My solution so far is this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN UPPER(psn.surname) LIKE '%INACTIVE%' THEN CONCAT(TRIM(REPLACE(psn.surname, '(Inactive)', '')), ', ', psn.firstname, ' (Inactive)')
      ELSE CONCAT(psn.surname, ', ', psn.firstname)
    END
  ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN UPPER(psn.surname) LIKE '%INACTIVE%' THEN CONCAT(TRIM(REPLACE(psn.surname, '(Inactive)', '')), ', ', psn.firstname, ' (Inactive)')
      ELSE CONCAT(psn.surname, ', ', psn.firstname)
    END
  ASC
  SEPARATOR '; '
) AS contacts
```

So far this works but it only looks for a specific string, there are also cases when the string within the curved brackets isn't `Inactive` and I don't want to hard code all of those.

So basically how do I move a string enclosed in curved brackets to the end of a string. I imagine `regex` is the best solution to this problem but I don't know how to use regex.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any regex functions that are useful for this. You have to use `LOCATE`, `SUBSTR`, and `CONCAT` to do it.

Comment: You might want to put it into a stored function.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` and `REGEXP_REPLACE()` the ones I need?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? They're new to that version.

Comment: @Barmar Oh okay. We're at 5.7 right now. Thanks for your suggestions. I'll look into them.

Comment: If you are using a case-insensitive collation for `surname`, you don't need to use `UPPER()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . something like this might work:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN psn.surname LIKE '%(%'
                            THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(psn.surname, '(', 1)), ', ',
                                        psn.firstname, '('
                                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(psn.surname, '(', -1)
                                       )
                            ELSE CONCAT(psn.surname, ', ', psn.firstname)
                       END)
              ORDER BY psn.surname, psn.firstname ASC SEPARATOR '; '
            ) AS contacts
```

I didn't repeat the expression for the `order by`.  That seems like overkill.